# How can I change the `invalid` message of doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using symfony with doctrine and I make a registration form. Email field is declared unique and if I set it to already existing one, I get the message `An object with the same "email" already exist.`. I use the following validator:

```
$this->validatorSchema['email'] = new sfValidatorEmail(array('required' => true), array('invalid' => 'Does not seem to be a proper email'));
```

How can I change the "already exists" message? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error on unique field you're seeing occurs at post-validation, so you need to override the validator there, you can do this like so in your form:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(
    array(
      'model' => 'Profile',
      'column' => array('email'),
      'throw_global_error' => false
    ),
    array(
      'invalid' => 'A user with that %column% already exists'
    )
  )
);
```

If you need to validate multiple fields e.g. the `username` stored in `sfGuardUser` you can pass an `sfValidatorAnd` (which accepts a single array of multiple validators) to `setPostValidator`.

Additionally: If you need to retain other existing validators it's worth looking into the `mergePostValidator` method.